# pretty faces configuration to remove folder from URL (JSF2.2 application deployed on Glassfish)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

I have JSF 2.2 application deployed on glassfish.
I wan't to beautify the URL

> http://MyWebsite/test/SOMEFOLDER/login.xhtml

to be

> http://MyWebsite/test/login.xhtml

I am using pretty faces using the follow configuration

```
<url-mapping id="login">
  <pattern value="/login.xhtml" />
  <view-id value="/SOMEFOLDER/login.xhtml" />
  <!-- Non JSF View Id -->
</url-mapping>
```

I am not adding anything in the web.xml

Comment: This should work fine. You should post more details. Like your web.xml. Did you set metadata-complete to true? Which Glassfish version are you using?

Comment: Hello I didn't add anything on web.xml  all configuration done in pretty faces.xml 

regarding the glassfish version 4.1

what do you mean by set metadata-complete to true ? where to set this

Comment: @Fares, `metadata-complete=true` could be a problem, that's an attribute set in the web.xml root tag and could prevent annoations to be read. If you have it, remove it. Anyway, did you make any test with the given example? Do you have any concrete issue?

Comment: I have tested many examples but not luck

Comment: Could you include the dependencies you added to your project in your question?